# Passing AccessToken into Xamarin Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: facebook, xamarin

I am retrieving the FB access token from another Xamarin login SDK I am using. Is it possible to set the access token manually and skipping the login view in the [Xamarin Facebook iOS SDK api](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios)?

[UPDATE]I am using the FB Invite feature like this and I am not sure how where to specify the access token if I already have it.

```
        var content = new AppInviteContent() { AppLinkURL = appLinkUrl, PreviewImageURL = previewImageUrl };
        AppInviteDialog.Show(content, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

since the Facebook User Access Tokens are portable [link here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens), I think you can handle the facebook button click, where you skip the fb login.

for example.

```
void FbButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(iHaveAccesToken)
        MissFbLogin();
    else
    _manager.LogInWithReadPermissions (EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS, (res, err) => FbLoginHandler (res, err));
}
```

And in your viewcontrollers send the graph request via gained AccesToken

Comment: I am using the AppInviteDialog feature which assumes Facebook SDK is already logged in and there is no way of specifing the access token. See code updates...